# Error in decryption of RSA data Java: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have problem with decryption (or maybe wrong encryption, too) of data with RSA in Java.
I wanna encrypt public key with some more info in String and then decrypt this public key and encrypt with it something (I use 2048 RSA):

Encryption:

```
public void saveExportToFile(String fileName, BigInteger mod, BigInteger exp, String info, PublicKey puk) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(baos));
    try {
        oout.writeObject(mod);
        oout.writeObject(exp);
        oout.writeChars(info);
        oout.close();
        baos.close();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, puk);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

        int i = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
        byte[] cipherData = null;
        while (i < data.length) {
            if (i+128 >= data.length) {
                buffer = new byte[data.length - i];
                System.arraycopy(data, i, buffer, 0, data.length - i);
                cipherData = cipher.doFinal(buffer);
                bos.write(cipherData);
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(data, i, buffer, 0, 128);
                cipherData = cipher.doFinal(buffer);
                bos.write(cipherData);
            }
            i += 128;
        }

        bos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected error", e);
    }
}
```

Decryption:

```
public void getDataFromRSA(String sendname, PrivateKey privateKey) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(sendname)));

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        int length = 0;
        int allLength = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
        byte[] bufferAC = null;
        byte[] outData = null;
        byte[] allData = null;
        byte[] tmpData = null;
        while ( (length = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            if (length < 128) {
                bufferAC = new byte[length];
                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, bufferAC, 0, length);
                outData = cipher.doFinal(bufferAC);
            } else {
                outData = cipher.doFinal(buffer); // HERE IS THE ERROR
            }
            allLength += outData.length;
            tmpData = allData;
            allData = new byte[allLength];
            System.arraycopy(tmpData, 0, allData, 0, tmpData.length);
            System.arraycopy(outData, 0, allData, tmpData.length, outData.length);
        }
    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | ClassNotFoundException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
OK, it seems I don't know about encryption as much as I thought. I'd like to use only RSA (if it's possible) since I don't need to transfer info more than once (size of info vary). I've edited encryption like this:

```
int i = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[245];
byte[] cipherData = null;
while (i < data.length) {
    if (i+245 >= data.length) {
        buffer = new byte[data.length - i];
        System.arraycopy(data, i, buffer, 0, data.length - i);
    } else {
        System.arraycopy(data, i, buffer, 0, 245);
    }
    cipherData = cipher.update(buffer);
    bos.write(cipherData);
    i += 245;
}
bos.write(cipher.doFinal()); // HERE IS THE ERROR
bos.close();
```

And now I get `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 245 bytes` (tried several lower values for buffer size). Is it because data length is not multiple of blocksize? Could this be fixed? Thanks for answers.

Comment: You should not use RSA as block cipher. In your scheme, an attacker can simply insert a previous block anywhere in your cipher without you noticing it during decryption. Hybrid encryption/decryption is not that hard, why don't you make an effort to do it right?

Comment: For your current problem: RSA has padding overhead, you should be putting at most 245 bytes in and decrypt per 256 bytes (11 bytes overhead). If you must, use doFinal in a loop with a 245 byte encrypt buffer and a 256 byte decrypt *input* buffer. Note that this does not fix your protocol, just your current implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I use hybrid cryptography now without problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should be using hybrid encryption, i.e. first encrypt the data using a symmetric cipher and then encrypt the random secret with an RSA key - sending both to the receiver.

Second, you should never have to perform `doFinal` in a loop for a single message. Use `update` and a single `doFinal` instead.

And thirdly, 2048 bits is 256 bytes. As long as you keep trying to decrypt 128 bytes instead of 256, you will get this exception. Usually I use `2048 / Byte.SIZE` instead, it makes the code more readable and will avoid mistakes.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thank you, now I learned something new in Java cryptography. I have just one question - what algorithms are save to use in plain Java (I used BouncyCastle before)? I'd like something universal. Now I use SHA-512, RSA 2048 and AES 128 (first I've tried AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding which I used with BouncyCastle but it gave me error while decryption)

Comment: Thats a strange set of parameters. You should use at least use a larger key size for RSA if you want to have a consistent level of security. See keylength.com . Never use ECB. If available, try GCM instead. OAEP would be a good idea for RSA.

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when you try to encrypt data with private key and decrypt with public key, you need to reverse this or you have to use a single key to encrypt and decrypt your data. This would solve this exception.